# CKeditor disable embedded multiples <span>

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

when we add styles for a text on CKEditor, he embedded that text with tag `<span>`, if I add a new style the CKEditor add more one tag `<span>`, like this:

```
<span style="font-size:18px;"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;"><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">TESTE</span></span></span>
```

But we need it to look like this (a single span with all styles):

```
<span style="font-size:18px;color:#FFFFFF;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">TESTE</span>
```

It is possible?